# Bash - How can I cut blocks of text into individual files, then place them back in after manipulation?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with this text in:

```
{{- if .Values.cxvxcxcvxcvx -}}
{{- if .Values.xcvxcvcxv.enabled }}
---
apiVersion: xx
kind: xcvxcv
metadata:
  name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
  namespace: xxxxxxxx
type: zxczxc
stringData:
  app-sql-host: gdsfgdfgdfg.dfgdfgdfgdg.zxczxczcc.xcvx.zxczxczc.com
  app-sql-database: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  app-sql-password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xx-sql-zxczx: xxxxxxxx
  xx-sql-zxczxc: xxxxxxxx
  sql-use-xx-user: 'no'
  app-sql-username: xxxxxxxx
{{- end }}
{{- if .Values.xcvxcv.enabled }}
---
apiVersion: xx
kind: xcvxcv
metadata:
  name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
  namespace: xxxxxxxx
type: xcv
stringData:
  xxx-url: xcvc:xcv://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx
{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

Here is the pseudo-code/steps I need to perform:

1. Get the text located between the first `---` and `{`.
2. Move/copy the text into a temporary file.
3. Repeat for each occurrence of text between any following `---` and `{`.
4. Run cat -n *<temp_file>* > *<temp_file>*
5. Insert each file's content back between the `---` and `{` where it came from.

Expected output:

```
{{- if .Values.cxvxcxcvxcvx -}}
{{- if .Values.xcvxcvcxv.enabled }}
---
apiVersion: xx
kind: xcvxcv
metadata:
  name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
  namespace: xxxxxxxx
type: zxczxc
encryptedData:
  app-sql-host: W8l4BFOTOzg4PDjjVVS7jrjhNy0WEcSjkWY0r93SK54cM1KM77bzSxAiNfwDW9liom8nESqezUcmX3V8A2IFMQJufNkOLUsUHAVPYWzAd0RqHhRHD6x2RkOsasGr46Jm3p14Dcz6oDYzETtwUhMJCVfAL7FXqqQWNOPXQyFhX7Oo05L7v34W4GGEDSwQo4ZqE9rJeYd4OXlsxkvfcIVqkZ5YsacczTXSsJWGdqPr3tsmplznaKZfkLqQgUzayXWdNI5H12FtBILqOr7TEdVEOVk2VkP7Nj4WZyrF00hbRhBi
  app-sql-database: W8l4BFOTOzg4PDjjVVS7jrjhNy0WEcSjkWY0r93SK54cM1KM77bzSxAiNfwDW9liom8nESqezUcmX3V8A2IFMQJufNkOLUsUHAVPYWzAd0RqHhRHD6x2RkOsasGr46Jm3p14Dcz6oDYzETtwUhMJCVfAL7FXqqQWNOPXQyFhX7Oo05L7v34W4GGEDSwQo4ZqE9rJeYd4OXlsxkvfcIVqkZ5YsacczTXSsJWGdqPr3tsmplznaKZfkLqQgUzayXWdNI5H12FtBILqOr7TEdVEOVk2VkP7Nj4WZyrF00hbRhBi
  app-sql-password: W8l4BFOTOzg4PDjjVVS7jrjhNy0WEcSjkWY0r93SK54cM1KM77bzSxAiNfwDW9liom8nESqezUcmX3V8A2IFMQJufNkOLUsUHAVPYWzAd0RqHhRHD6x2RkOsasGr46Jm3p14Dcz6oDYzETtwUhMJCVfAL7FXqqQWNOPXQyFhX7Oo05L7v34W4GGEDSwQo4ZqE9rJeYd4OXlsxkvfcIVqkZ5YsacczTXSsJWGdqPr3tsmplznaKZfkLqQgUzayXWdNI5H12FtBILqOr7TEdVEOVk2VkP7Nj4WZyrF00hbRhBi
  xx-sql-zxczx: W8l4BFOTOzg4PDjjVVS7jrjhNy0WEcSjkWY0r93SK54cM1KM77bzSxAiNfwDW9liom8nESqezUcmX3V8A2IFMQJufNkOLUsUHAVPYWzAd0RqHhRHD6x2RkOsasGr46Jm3p14Dcz6oDYzETtwUhMJCVfAL7FXqqQWNOPXQyFhX7Oo05L7v34W4GGEDSwQo4ZqE9rJeYd4OXlsxkvfcIVqkZ5YsacczTXSsJWGdqPr3tsmplznaKZfkLqQgUzayXWdNI5H12FtBILqOr7TEdVEOVk2VkP7Nj4WZyrF00hbRhBi
  xx-sql-zxczxc: W8l4BFOTOzg4PDjjVVS7jrjhNy0WEcSjkWY0r93SK54cM1KM77bzSxAiNfwDW9liom8nESqezUcmX3V8A2IFMQJufNkOLUsUHAVPYWzAd0RqHhRHD6x2RkOsasGr46Jm3p14Dcz6oDYzETtwUhMJCVfAL7FXqqQWNOPXQyFhX7Oo05L7v34W4GGEDSwQo4ZqE9rJeYd4OXlsxkvfcIVqkZ5YsacczTXSsJWGdqPr3tsmplznaKZfkLqQgUzayXWdNI5H12FtBILqOr7TEdVEOVk2VkP7Nj4WZyrF00hbRhBi
  sql-use-xx-user: W8l4BFOTOzg4PDjjVVS7jrjhNy0WEcSjkWY0r93SK54cM1KM77bzSxAiNfwDW9liom8nESqezUcmX3V8A2IFMQJufNkOLUsUHAVPYWzAd0RqHhRHD6x2RkOsasGr46Jm3p14Dcz6oDYzETtwUhMJCVfAL7FXqqQWNOPXQyFhX7Oo05L7v34W4GGEDSwQo4ZqE9rJeYd4OXlsxkvfcIVqkZ5YsacczTXSsJWGdqPr3tsmplznaKZfkLqQgUzayXWdNI5H12FtBILqOr7TEdVEOVk2VkP7Nj4WZyrF00hbRhBi
  app-sql-username: W8l4BFOTOzg4PDjjVVS7jrjhNy0WEcSjkWY0r93SK54cM1KM77bzSxAiNfwDW9liom8nESqezUcmX3V8A2IFMQJufNkOLUsUHAVPYWzAd0RqHhRHD6x2RkOsasGr46Jm3p14Dcz6oDYzETtwUhMJCVfAL7FXqqQWNOPXQyFhX7Oo05L7v34W4GGEDSwQo4ZqE9rJeYd4OXlsxkvfcIVqkZ5YsacczTXSsJWGdqPr3tsmplznaKZfkLqQgUzayXWdNI5H12FtBILqOr7TEdVEOVk2VkP7Nj4WZyrF00hbRhBi
{{- end }}
{{- if .Values.xcvxcv.enabled }}
---
apiVersion: xx
kind: xcvxcv
metadata:
  name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
  namespace: xxxxxxxx
type: xcv
encryptedData:
  xxx-url: W8l4BFOTOzg4PDjjVVS7jrjhNy0WEcSjkWY0r93SK54cM1KM77bzSxAiNfwDW9liom8nESqezUcmX3V8A2IFMQJufNkOLUsUHAVPYWzAd0RqHhRHD6x2RkOsasGr46Jm3p14Dcz6oDYzETtwUhMJCVfAL7FXqqQWNOPXQyFhX7Oo05L7v34W4GGEDSwQo4ZqE9rJeYd4OXlsxkvfcIVqkZ5YsacczTXSsJWGdqPr3tsmplznaKZfkLqQgUzayXWdNI5H12FtBILqOr7TEdVEOVk2VkP7Nj4WZyrF00hbRhBi
  username: W8l4BFOTOzg4PDjjVVS7jrjhNy0WEcSjkWY0r93SK54cM1KM77bzSxAiNfwDW9liom8nESqezUcmX3V8A2IFMQJufNkOLUsUHAVPYWzAd0RqHhRHD6x2RkOsasGr46Jm3p14Dcz6oDYzETtwUhMJCVfAL7FXqqQWNOPXQyFhX7Oo05L7v34W4GGEDSwQo4ZqE9rJeYd4OXlsxkvfcIVqkZ5YsacczTXSsJWGdqPr3tsmplznaKZfkLqQgUzayXWdNI5H12FtBILqOr7TEdVEOVk2VkP7Nj4WZyrF00hbRhBi
  password: W8l4BFOTOzg4PDjjVVS7jrjhNy0WEcSjkWY0r93SK54cM1KM77bzSxAiNfwDW9liom8nESqezUcmX3V8A2IFMQJufNkOLUsUHAVPYWzAd0RqHhRHD6x2RkOsasGr46Jm3p14Dcz6oDYzETtwUhMJCVfAL7FXqqQWNOPXQyFhX7Oo05L7v34W4GGEDSwQo4ZqE9rJeYd4OXlsxkvfcIVqkZ5YsacczTXSsJWGdqPr3tsmplznaKZfkLqQgUzayXWdNI5H12FtBILqOr7TEdVEOVk2VkP7Nj4WZyrF00hbRhBi
template:
  metadata:
    annotations:
      sealedsecrets.bitnami.com/<example-pathparameter>: "true"
{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

I think AWK is the best way to do this but I'm open to other Bash solutions. `gawk` is not available to me.

Comment: What is the nature of the commands in #4? You can do this all in one go with Perl. `perl -0777 -lnE 'while (/^(---[^{]+)/gm) {do_your_commands}' file`

Comment: @dawg The command in #4 encrypts a few sensitive values and adds fields, however it can't accept the whole file above at once. The file above has to be split into individual files first, use the individual files against the command, then reassembled. The end result would look fairly similar to the file above but with long encrypted strings

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input. Pick some common command to use for step #4 (e.g. `md5sum` or `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'` or `wc` or anything else) if the real command you need to use isn't readily available. Clarify if the command you want to call truly needs a temp file to operate on or if it can just accept piped input and produce output stdout. Also state if you have or can get GNU awk and, if not, what awk version you do have.

Comment: When you say `echo foo.yaml | kubeseal` in your question - do you REALLY mean that or do you actually mean `cat foo.yaml | kubeseal`? Since `kubeseal` isn't a common Unix command, as I suggested in my previous comment your question would be improved by using a common Unix tool (any tool that takes piped input and outputs to stdout, e.g. `cat -n` as I used in my answer) as the tool to be called since it'd then be testable by others. You also haven't told us yet if you have GNU awk (for coprocesses) or not.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too good at this. I shouldn't have assumed temp files were necessary so now I'm wondering if I should change the whole question or make a new one. I'm just trying to run a command on individual blocks of text then insert the output back in their respective positions. gawk is not available to me.

Comment: @M455 I updated my answer to include a solution that doesn't use a temp file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really not convinced you need your command to modify the temp file so here's a solution that will work with any awk that implements `fflush()` (which is most of them and will be required by POSIX in the upcoming 2022 standards release, see https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=634 for details) and uses a temp file (probably not necessary at all if you have GNU awk for co-processes) but assumes your command you run on it can print to stdout:

```
$ cat tst.awk
inBlock {
    if ( /^{/ ) {
        fflush()
        close(tmp)
        cmd = "cat -n \047" tmp "\047"
        while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
            print line
        }
        close(cmd)
        inBlock = 0
    }
    else {
        print > tmp
    }
}

!inBlock

/^---/ { inBlock = 1 }
```

```
$ tmp=$(mktemp) && awk -v tmp="$tmp" -f tst.awk file && rm -f "$tmp"
{{- if .Values.cxvxcxcvxcvx -}}
{{- if .Values.xcvxcvcxv.enabled }}
---
     1  apiVersion: xx
     2  kind: xcvxcv
     3  metadata:
     4    name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
     5    namespace: xxxxxxxx
     6  type: zxczxc
     7  stringData:
     8    app-sql-host: gdsfgdfgdfg.dfgdfgdfgdg.zxczxczcc.xcvx.zxczxczc.com
     9    app-sql-database: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    10    app-sql-password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    11    xx-sql-zxczx: xxxxxxxx
    12    xx-sql-zxczxc: xxxxxxxx
    13    sql-use-xx-user: 'no'
    14    app-sql-username: xxxxxxxx
{{- end }}
{{- if .Values.xcvxcv.enabled }}
---
     1  apiVersion: xx
     2  kind: xcvxcv
     3  metadata:
     4    name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
     5    namespace: xxxxxxxx
     6  type: xcv
     7  stringData:
     8    xxx-url: xcvc:xcv://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
     9    username: xxxx
    10    password: xxxx
{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

Obviously replace `cat -n` with whatever command you really want to run on the temp files.

---

EDIT: without using a temp file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
inBlock {
    if ( /^{/ ) {
        fflush()
        cmd = "cat -n"
        print buf | cmd
        close(cmd)
        buf = ""
        inBlock = 0
    }
    else {
        buf = (inBlock++ > 1 ? buf ORS : "") $0
    }
}

!inBlock

/^---/ { inBlock = 1 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
{{- if .Values.cxvxcxcvxcvx -}}
{{- if .Values.xcvxcvcxv.enabled }}
---
     1  apiVersion: xx
     2  kind: xcvxcv
     3  metadata:
     4    name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
     5    namespace: xxxxxxxx
     6  type: zxczxc
     7  stringData:
     8    app-sql-host: gdsfgdfgdfg.dfgdfgdfgdg.zxczxczcc.xcvx.zxczxczc.com
     9    app-sql-database: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    10    app-sql-password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    11    xx-sql-zxczx: xxxxxxxx
    12    xx-sql-zxczxc: xxxxxxxx
    13    sql-use-xx-user: 'no'
    14    app-sql-username: xxxxxxxx
{{- end }}
{{- if .Values.xcvxcv.enabled }}
---
     1  apiVersion: xx
     2  kind: xcvxcv
     3  metadata:
     4    name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
     5    namespace: xxxxxxxx
     6  type: xcv
     7  stringData:
     8    xxx-url: xcvc:xcv://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
     9    username: xxxx
    10    password: xxxx
{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: @Roadowl - the OP has sample input, expected output, and pseudo-code of what they're trying to do. People get answers with far less.

Comment: Then the question should have been tagged pseudo-code, and the answer should have been in pseudo-code.  "People get answers with far less." -- agreed, very much.

Comment: @Roadowl when people show their attempt with a shell read loop or with sed and tag the question with awk we aren't constrained to only providing shell read loop or sed answers and the same applies for pseudo-code. Any attempt is still an attempt and deserves some help. In this case I provided a code-only answer so the OP can google, look up man pages, etc. to learn how the constructs I used in awk work and so learn how to do similar tasks themselves in future.